# WSL2 Jupyter Notebook error Powershell cannot find file specified

Tags: powershell, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

I am excited about the wsl2 and then straightaway installed Anaconda for setting up my DS environment.

Following [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-a-data-science-environment-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-c4b390803dd)

After I typed

```
jupyter notebook
```

I see this error.

Could anyone give some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Found [another article](https://www.emilykauffman.com/teaching/install-anaconda-on-wsl)

It seems that this error is cause by missing of browser(GUI) in the WSL, so that is why this error happens.

I then run

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

No it doesn't show the error.

Could someone confirm my guess?